# Modification of java regex

Tags: java, regex

I was using the below regex to substitute file names

```
Regex -> .*\/([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})_(O).*.cmd
Substitution -> $1
```

The file names were like below:

```
File Name                         | Substituted Name
---------------------------------- ------------------
/V3/OGM_REC_Offline_Level0_4D.cmd  OGM_REC
/V2/PIE_PROD_Online_Level1_6D.cmd  PIE_PROD
/V3/BR2_OnDemand.cmd               BR2
/opt/STING_Online_Inc0_1W.cmd      STING
```

Then the files changed and I modified the regex

```
Regex -> .*\/([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})(_O|Full).*.cmd
Substitution -> $1
```

Additional new file names

```
File Name             | Substituted Name
---------------------- ------------------
/opt/RSU10Full.cmd     RSU10
/V4/REZ40_1Full.cmd    REZ40_1
```

Now, it seems there are new files are getting updated with below name formats

```
/app/OMGIT_FullOnDemand_4W.cmd
/admin/FOC_STG_Full_6D.cmd
```

I've modified the regex again, but it's not getting successful

```
Regex -> .*\/([A-Z0-9_]{1,9})(_O|Full|_Full).*.cmd
Substitution -> $1
```

Comment: Try `.*/([A-Z0-9_]{1,9}?)(_O|_?Full).*[.]cmd`.

Comment: @stribizhev , Shouldn't you post this as an answer ? I've tested it and it's working for the examples that I have... I'll be doing a extensive tests using this on Monday... Thanks for your quick reply...

Comment: OK, let me post and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a version with a *lazy* limiting quantifier `{1,9}?` and optional `_`:

```
.*/([A-Z0-9_]{1,9}?)(_O|_?Full).*[.]cmd
```

This way, we match as few characters with `[A-Z0-9_]{1,9}?`  as possible to return a valid captured subtext, and `_?Full` part can hold the optional underscore.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qL2vW9/1)

Comment: If you get more complicated patterns on Monday, feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that unnecessary tail is allways started with: (optional) _, letter in uppercase, letter in lowercase.
So, universal solution is:

```
.*\/([^a-z]*?)[_]?[A-Z][a-z].*
```